# Select by name and get the Id of the selected item with Angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, html

I am working in an MVC project with HTML and angular. 
I have a select list which get selected based on a name entered in an input box, but I am not able to get the id.

This works but I don't get the Id of the selected item:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedCountry">
    <select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="selectedCountry" 
    ng-options="country.name as country.name for country in countries">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
```

And this is not working, as I am not able to select by the name and get the id:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedCountry">
  <select class="form-control" 
    ng-model="selectedCountry" 
    ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries">
<option value="">Select Country</option>
```

Here is the plunker: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fPv3NURiNamS5KoF2vdN?p=preview)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the second scenario to work you'll need to get the id of the country in your controller like this:

```
  $scope.selectedCountry = $scope.countries.find(function(country) {
    return country.name === "Italy";
  }).id;
```

Comment: that is right ! That is what I am trying to avoid, it is possible to avoid this by doing all in a declaritive mode in HTML?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Whether you derive the id or entire object from the provided name (Italy) or do some jQuery manipulation ... all of your options point to controller code.

Comment: Thanks to all for the great help!

Answer (score 2):

```
<select class="form-control"  data-ng-change="call(country.id)"
        ng-model="country.id" 
        ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedCountryId">
  <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCountryId">
  <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>
<div>selected country id: {{selectedCountryId}} </div>
```

in controller add `$scope.selectedCountryId = "";`

[image]

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedCountry.name">
  <select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="selectedCountry" 
        ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>

  </select>
```

In your HTML

and

```
$scope.selectedCountry = {};
```

in your javascript

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible when you use the same model on different select which are using different keys for the model.

I would go with using the name in both models and then fetching the id from the array:

```
$scope.getId = function(){
    var co = $scope.countries.filter(function (el) {  return el.name == $scope.selectedCountry });
      if(typeof co !== 'undefined' && co.length > 0){
        $scope.selectedId =co[0].id;
      }else{
        $scope.selectedId = null;
      }
  };
```

plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/qAWc1mPFqrq4Ohb85QSA?p=preview)